# Nested Select Queries Grouped by Date

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, subquery

I have a table called 'rawTweets' which looks like the following

```
tweet, date, id, username, compoundScore
```

I want to calculate the averages for certain keywords and group the results by date, but am a little stuck (still very much a sql 'newb'). In my head, it looks something like the following.

Could use a little guidance - thank you!

```
SELECT
    `date`,
    AVG(
        SELECT compoundScore 
        FROM rawTweets 
        WHERE tweet LIKE '%trump%'
    ) AS Trump,
    AVG(
        SELECT compoundScore 
        FROM rawTweets 
        WHERE tweet LIKE '%chaffetz%'
    ) as Chaffetz
FROM rawTweets 
WHERE 
    compoundScore <> 0.0 
    AND compoundScore IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `date`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `nested select` you do, you can try this one mate:

```
SELECT
    `date`,
    AVG(COALESCE(rt2.compoundScore, 0)) AS Trump,
    AVG(COALESCE(rt3.compoundScore, 0)) AS Chaffetz
FROM 
    rawTweets rt
    -- Trump
    LEFT JOIN rawTweets rt2 ON
        rt2.id = rt.id
        AND rt2.tweet LIKE '%trump%'
    -- Chaffetz
    LEFT JOIN rawTweets rt3 ON
        rt3.id = rt.id
        AND rt3.tweet LIKE '%chaffetz%'
WHERE
    compoundScore <> 0.0
    AND compoundScore IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `date`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `avg` and `case when` to do this:

```
select date
  ,avg(case when tweet like '%trump%' then compoundScore else null end) as Trump
  ,avg(case when tweet like '%chaffetz%' then compoundScore else null end) as Chaffetz
from rawTweets
where compoundScore <> 0.0 and compoundScore is not null
group by date
```